# Helper data not found in custom module, error on show in phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

> Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Webtouch_Reseller>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Webtouch_Reseller>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <reseller>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Webtouch_Reseller</module>
                    <frontName>reseller</frontName>
                </args>
            </reseller>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <reseller>
                    <file>reseller.xml</file>
                </reseller>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <reseller>
                <class>Webtouch_Reseller_Helper</class>
            </reseller>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <reseller>
                <class>Webtouch_Reseller_Block</class>
            </reseller>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <reseller>
                <class>Webtouch_Reseller_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>reseller_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </reseller>
            <reseller_mysql4>
                <class>Webtouch_Reseller_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <reseller>
                        <table>wt_reseller</table>
                    </reseller>
                </entities>
            </reseller_mysql4>
        </models>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Webtouch_Reseller before="Mage_Adminhtml">Webtouch_Reseller_Adminhtml</Webtouch_Reseller>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <reseller>
                    <file>reseller.xml</file>
                </reseller>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

> Model

```
<?php

class Webtouch_Reseller_Model_Reseller extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('reseller/reseller');
    }
}
```

> Block

```
<?php 
class Webtouch_Reseller_Block_Reseller extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
}
```

> Phtml

```
Mage::helper('webtouch_reseller')
?>

<div class="uk-container uk-container-center">

<form id="resellerForm" method="post" class="uk-form uk-width-1-1">
      <div class="uk-form-row">
            <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-small uk-grid-width-small-1-1 uk-grid-width-medium-1-3" data-uk-grid-margin>
                <div>                        
                    <input style="padding: 15px;height: 60px;border: 1px solid #757576;" name="name" required id="name" placeholder="<?= Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('Reseller')->__('Name')) ?>*" title="<?= Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('Reseller')->__('Name')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('Reseller')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry uk-form-large" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input style="padding: 15px;height: 60px;border: 1px solid #757576;" name="email" required id="email" placeholder="<?= Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('Reseller')->__('Email')) ?>*" title="<?= Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('Reseller')->__('Email')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('Reseller')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email uk-form-large" type="email" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input style="padding: 15px;height: 60px;border: 1px solid #757576;" name="cnpj" required id="cnpj" placeholder="cnpj" class="input-text required-entry validate-email uk-form-large" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input style="padding: 15px;height: 60px;border: 1px solid #757576;" name="company" required id="company" placeholder="<?= Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('Reseller')->__('Company Name')) ?>*" title="<?= Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('Reseller')->__('Company')) ?>"class="input-text required-entry validate-email uk-form-large" type="email" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input style="padding: 15px;height: 60px;border: 1px solid #757576;" name="phone" required id="phone" placeholder="<?= Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('Reseller')->__('phone')) ?>*" title="<?= Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('Reseller')->__('phone')) ?>"  class="input-text required-entry validate-email uk-form-large" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select style="padding: 15px;height: 60px;border: 1px solid #757576;" name="state" id="state" class="uk-form-large uk-width-1-1 input-text">
                        <option value=""><?= Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('Reseller')->__('State')) ?>*</option>
                        <option value="Atendimento">Atendimento</option>
                        <option value="Duvidas">Duvidas</option>
                        <option value="Reclamações">Reclamações</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p> 
        <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit')) ?>" class="button uk-button uk-margin-top wt-button--primary"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('resellerForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

> Error

```
Warning: include(/Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Webtouch_Reseller_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94

#0 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php(94): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(/Users/...', '/Users/webtouch...', 94, Array)
#1 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php(94): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Webtouch_R...')
#3 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/app/Mage.php(547): spl_autoload_call('Mage_Webtouch_R...')
#4 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/app/design/frontend/sly/default/template/reseller/reseller.phtml(13): Mage::helper('webtouch_resell...')
#5 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3428): include('/Users/webtouch...')
#6 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3459): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/sly/de...')
#7 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3473): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2617): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/app/design/frontend/sly/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml(29): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3428): include('/Users/webtouch...')
#11 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3459): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/sly/de...')
#12 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3473): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2617): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2335): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2279): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('footer', true)
#16 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/app/design/frontend/sly/default/template/page/1column.phtml(73): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('footer')
#17 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3428): include('/Users/webtouch...')
#18 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3459): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/sly/de...')
#19 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(3473): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2617): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28814): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14306): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#23 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(11657): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#24 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(11572): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '16')
#25 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/PageController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_PageController), '16')
#26 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14334): Mage_Cms_PageController->viewAction()
#27 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18813): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18343): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21279): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /Users/webtouch/Projects/Web/Sly/Labbo/public_html/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error mentions directory `public_html/includes/` which is mainly just used for Magento 1.x's Compiler. The compiler is actually a legacy feature for performance improvements back before OPcache came bundled in PHP5.5+.

If you're using PHP5.5+ and can verify that OPcache is running (run `php -v` in your terminal and you'll get output with something like `with Zend OPcache....`) then I'd recommend just disabling Magento's compiler under the `System > Tools > Compilation` page and then flush your cache.

Comment: Thanks it`s work

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update This line Mage::helper("Reseller") To Mage::helper('reseller') and your issue may solve,

i hope this will help you !!!

Happy Codding !!

Answer (score 0):

`Mage::helper('Reseller')` replace this code to `Mage::helper('reseller')`

**I hope this will you help!!!**